# Convergence in probability of a random variable multiplied by n

Tags: probability, statistics

I'm trying to solve this 2 part example and the first part is trivial to show but I get confused about the second part. Because i know the solution it is easy to fool myself into thinking I understand it but I don't want that. I want to understand. So here goes:

For $\boldsymbol{n} \geq \boldsymbol{1}$, let $\boldsymbol{X}_{\boldsymbol{n}}$ be a Poisson random variable with parameter
$1 / n$.

What can you conclude?

$\square$ $\boldsymbol{X}_{\boldsymbol{n}} \rightarrow \mathbf{0}$ in probability, but $\boldsymbol{n X}_{\boldsymbol{n}}$ does not converge in probability

$\square$ $\boldsymbol{X}_{n} \rightarrow 0$ in probability, $\boldsymbol{n X}_{n} \rightarrow 0$ in probability, and $\mathbb{E}\left[\left(\boldsymbol{n X}_{n}\right)^{2}\right]$ converges.

$\square$ $\boldsymbol{X}_{n} \rightarrow 0$ and $n X_{n} \rightarrow 0$ in probability, but $\mathbb{E}\left[\left(n X_{n}\right)^{2}\right]$ does not converge.

I started by wanting to prove $X_n$ converges in probability to 0. That was the easier bit:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} P(|X_n-0|>\epsilon)=0\Leftrightarrow\lim_{n\to\infty} P(|e^{-\frac{1}{n}}-0|>\epsilon)=0$$
Where I replaced $X_n$ by its pmf at point 0.

Is this ok to write? Now I'm questioning the use of P on the RHS of above as I'm already using: $$\mathbf{P}\left(X_{n}=0\right)=\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{0} \frac{1}{0 !} \exp \left(-\frac{1}{n}\right)=\exp \left(-\frac{1}{n}\right)$$

What I ask of you is:

Please help me be more precise about these statements

Help me prove $\boldsymbol{n X}_{\boldsymbol{n}}$ does converge in probability as well.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P(X_n=0) =e^{-1/n} \to 1$ so $P(|X|_n >\epsilon) \leq P(X_n \neq 0)=1-P(X_n=0) \to 0$.

$P(|nX_n|>\epsilon)=P(X_n >\frac {\epsilon} n) =1-P(X_n=0) \to 0$ so both $(X_n)$ and $(nX_n)$ tend to $0$ in probability.

$E(nX_n)^{2}=n^{2}EX_n^{2}$. I will leave it to you to write down the second moment of $X_n$ and see if  $E(nX_n)^{2}$ converges.